# Is there a saying like "Plum trees bloom most beautifully as they stand and overcome the cold severe winter."?

Tags: popular-refrains

Is there a saying like "Plum trees bloom most beautifully as they stand and overcome the cold severe winter."? It is a part of Japanese poem translated into English. It basically means a great achievement cannot be conveyed without overcoming great difficulties or sufferings; it is important to keep doing your best even in bad circumstances.

Comment: [Here](http://www.quotegarden.com/adversity.html) are a couple of hundred. There are numerous other sites with thousands of others found by simply searching *adversity sayings*. This looks like a general reference question.

Comment: Good resource, bib - though by no means all the references refer to the benefits of enduring and overcoming suffering. I've taken the liberty of quoting two that do:  

                                                                                         Smooth seas do not make skillful sailors.  ~African Proverb


There is no education like adversity.  ~Disraeli

Comment: @bib Interesting, but I don't think any of them *quite* describe the very Japanese sensibility of beauty in adversity.  The English language quote convey more of the sense of "that which does not destroy me makes me stronger" kind.

Comment: @Teno I don't think you'll find the kind of answers you're looking for on this forum.  I suggest you take your question to writers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @bib: most of those are _quotes_, but that's not quite the same thing as a _proverb_ or _saying_. I think the O.P. is asking for something widely-known, not just catchy and clever.

Comment: @J.R. Personally quotes are also welcome. I've been wondering how I could tell somebody in English my favorite phrases if the phrases are not English. And wondered if there is a very close English expression to the sentence asked in the question.

Comment: @bib Sorry if you got offended by the question.

Comment: @Teno: Presumably your example isn't a "saying" either - it just happens to be one particular translation of one particular Japanese poem. One well-established saying that comes to mind is [per ardua ad astra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_astra_(phrase)) (approximately *"a rough road leads to the stars"*), but that's Latin anyway.

Comment: @Teno I am not offended. We try to limit this site to discussions that lead to fairly discrete answers. We also hope that questioners try to do a little research themselves before turning to the site. Your question is open to so many answers that it does not seem like a good fit.

Comment: @Teno These two just can to mind: "We can complain because rose bushes have thorns, or rejoice because thorn bushes have roses." "You have to kiss a lot of frogs before you find your handsome prince." The list of so many possible answers is the problem.

Comment: @bib they don't have quite the same meaning. Now I think Pitarou's comment is the best answer: `I don't think any of them quite describe the very Japanese sensibility of beauty in adversity.`

Comment: @Teno - the Mulan quote, "The flower that blooms in adversity is the rarest and most beautiful of all" may be closest in meaning.

Comment: @Bib - While I, too, posted a quote, I'd argue that your response does not answer the question as asked (it asks for a "saying", such as which is not at all the same thing as a quote), and no simple Google search can. The close rationale, then, seems false, and the question should probably be reopened.

Comment: @Teno - consider also "beauty through adversity", which is a reasonably common saying.

Answer (score 3):

Not so poetic, but we have *No pain, no gain.* Or, as the Irish poet W B Yeats wrote,

> I said ‘It’s certain there is no fine thing
>
> Since Adam’s fall but needs much labouring.'

Answer (score 2):

[When the going gets tough, the tough get going](http://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Sayings/Quizzes/Modern/When_the_going_gets_tough_the_tough_get_going_1314.htm) *- when a situation is difficult or dangerous, strong people work harder to resolve the problem.*

Answer (score 1):

It's not as colourful as the Japanese, but an alternative to "it is important to keep doing your best even in bad circumstances." is

> [If life gives you lemons, make lemonade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_life_gives_you_lemons,_make_lemonade).

It doesn't cover the magnitude of the suffering however

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a saying but I found it very close in the lyrics of Bette Midler's song, The Rose.

> When the night has been too lonely and the road has been to long,
>
> and you think that love is only for the lucky and the strong,
>
> just remember in the winter far beneath the bitter snow
>
> lies the seed that with the sun's love in the spring becomes the rose.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oR6okRuOLc8